# Is this set a Field?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $F$ be the following set:

$F = \mathbb{Z} \cup $ {$ \pm\frac {1} {2}, \pm\frac {1} {3},\pm\frac {1} {4},\pm\frac {1} {5} $......}

Is this set (with the usual addition and multiplication of numbers) a field? Explain.

*How to do these type of questions? I have no idea.*

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\not\in F$.

Comment: Do you mean 
$F = \mathbb{Z} \cup $ {$ \pm\frac {1} {2}, \pm\frac {1} {3},\pm\frac {1} {4},\pm\frac {1} {5} \pm \ldots$}? Just those four fractions on their own won't do. The question involving, however, the fractions through $\frac1n$ is far more interesting.

Comment: Any question of the form "is thing $X$ a $Y$" can be answered by looking through your textbook/notes for the definition, and seeing whether $X$ fits that definition.  In this case, you need to use the definition of a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To tell if something is a field, it needs to satisfy a collection of axioms, including

- Closure under the operation $+$
- Closure under the operation $*$
- Associativity and commutativity of both operations

and so on. As a start, check whether this set is closed under either of the operations.